# Is it ok to make Factory Class responsible to create a Collection of Objects instead of One at a time

Tags: iphone, ios, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am creating a Menu application for a Coffee shop which has 4 different flavors of Coffee. 
 1. Black Coffe 
 2. Cappuccino 
 3. Mocha 
 4. Iced Coffe.

I have used factory method to generate these objects.

```
+ (Coffee *) getInstance:(COFFE_TYPE /*Enumeration*/):type{

   Coffee *returnValue = nil;

   switch(type){
     case Black: returnValue = new Black_Coffee();
                 break;
    case Cappuccino: returnValue = new Cap_Coffee();
                 break;
    case Mocha: returnValue = new Mocha_Coffee();
                 break;
    case Iced: returnValue = new Iced_Coffee();
                 break;

    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

In my Client I have to maintain a List of all available Coffee . I believe there is no way to get to know the subclasses for a given base class so I have to manually iterate over all my subclasses and use factory method for creation of each Object . This will become messy once I have 50 different types of coffee (which I will). So every time I add a new type I have to add it into the factory as well my client need to which additional item is added .

Is there a way so that I can transfer this entire logic at one place . So that just factory method would only know about the additional items and my client can call getAllItems on factory class itself and iterate over them or I should let my client handle the collection of items (which is the case right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would handle this is create a static NSMutableDictionary, and when your app starts up, you can register the known coffee types using a new class method. The class method will do a setObject:forKey on the dictionary. Provide some means for the client to register as many objects as he wants, knowing that each "key" (name) has to be unique. That said, he could even overwrite the initial items you create by using the same key (and replace what ever object it is that is associate with that type.

I would use names not numbers (as you have now), but if you want to stick with numbers that works as long as you use a NSNumber for the key in the dictionary.

Comment: excellent !! I would definitely prefer that . The only concerned which I have is that factory pattern is standard and ubiquitous through out my code . It helps other people to easily Identify the purpose of this class on the other hand people would generally find to difficult to interpret the use of NSMuatableDictionary(Objective C does not have generics either :( .. ) and its purpose without reading documentation. I was thinking of a more elegant solution so that I can wrap up this NSMutableDictionary in a Factory class? How about that ?

Comment: Sorry, you missed my point. The dictionary is internal. You add new class methods to add a type, to provide an array of all types (this is just the dictionary keys), etc. User does not see the dictionary. Its just extends what you have done so far. The factory method you have just saves them in the dictionary, then vends copies out as needed.

Comment: gr8 I think factory method need a redefinition .. I have faced this issue several time but failed to come up with an elegant solution .. thank you

Comment: The term "factory method" refers to a class method the returns instances of the same class. What I'm really proposing is to just use a class todo what you want - all class methods. It may return some objects but they don't need to be of the same type as the class (they could be dictionaries or other objects).

Comment: In objective-c, this pattern is referred to as a class cluster, and it is perfectly acceptable if the user doesn't need to know the specifics of the concrete classes.

Comment: Well, I'd argue a class cluster is a bit different but my opinion. This is more like a "simple" singleton that has no ivars - just the one static global to hold information.

Comment: @borrrden I believe that class cluster goes one level up with the factory method and creates an abstract class which serves as an interface to many other subclasses but It is not responsible to keep a track of count for all its subclasses and to return me a collection which contains all the subclasses (please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @KunalBalani The class cluster will use a dictionary or some other logic internally to determine which class to make, but you are correct that it will use one interface to represent them all (like you Coffee class right?  You return "Coffee" but you actually create "Mocha").  Although you could say since the user known about the existence of them that it is not technically a cluster, but instead a factory (actually the two are very similar...)

Comment: @DavidH Yes, factory and cluster are actually pretty similar.  So similar in fact that it probably doesn't matter which term you use.  Although, since this is not happening in the init method I think I will yield and call it a factory instead.